# Android: where do PackageManager and SensorManager get their information?

Tags: android, android-package-managers, sensormanager

On Android, to find out the available system features you can do something like:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
for (FeatureInfo fi : pm.getSystemAvailableFeatures()) {
    String feature_name = fi.name;
    if(fi.name == null){
        feature_name = "GlEs Version " + fi.getGlEsVersion();
    }
    Log.i("theTag", feature_name + "");
}
```

Similarly, to find out the available sensors you can do something like:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensor_list = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for (Sensor s : sensor_list) {
    Log.i("theTag", s.getName() + " - type: " + s.getType());
}
```

My question is how does Android know what the PackageManager and SensorManager should report?  Do the device manufacturers provide some kind of manifest or does the system poll the components to see what is available?  Which of the two is more authoritative in the event of a conflict?

Comment: If you really want to know, look for the sources – Android is Open Source, after all.

Comment: What possible conflict can there be between `PackageManager` and `SensorManager`?

Comment: I have a device that reports android.hardware.sensor.proximity as false, but simultaneously names a proximity sensor when the SensorManager is queried.

Answer (score 0):

**Android** is a stack of software and firmwares, which include Operating system, inbuilt applications and System services.

We can write our own services to provide some data to our applications. Like wise, we can use system services which provide some data to us. Thats why there is a call `SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 0):

> The list of all sensors present on the device is reported by the HAL
> implementation.

From: https://source.android.com/devices/sensors

The HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) gets its information from the drivers, which gets its info from the sensor hub.

[image: The Android Sensor stack from https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-stack. Applications > SDK > Framework > HAL > Drivers > Sensors hub > Sensors]

Read more about the Android Sensor stack on the official page: https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-stack